# What are these brands, advertisers, broadcasters and publishers in instagram?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I need public_content permission of instagram, when i applied for it the team denied it with comment 
public_content:

"This permission (public_content) is only granted to apps that enable brands, advertisers, broadcasters and publishers to discover public content. We do not grant access to apps that do not fall into these categories. Please review our documentation (https://www.instagram.com/developer/review) for more information."

This permission is needed and vary important for my plugin which uses below code to change username with their corresponding user id:

code:
'https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/search?q='.$this->username.'&access_token='.$this->access_token'

Now i want to know 2 things here:

1- Is there any alternative code for plugin to replace with.
2- What are these brands, advertisers, broadcasters and publishers in instagram.

Comment: 1. No alternative, you must get your app approved. 2. Confusing as can be, don't understand it yet myself. Makes no sense why people are downvoting. This is a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

1. No alternative, you must get your app approved.
2. Confusing as can be, don't understand it yet myself.

Makes no sense why people are downvoting the question. It's pretty valid.